# Movie in which water is imported from past

Tags: time-travel, story-identification

About 10 years ago, I watched a Sci-Fi movie or telefilm on TV. It featured future of Earth when water would be a historical thing of past. They developed a time portal to travel in past i.e. current century. The full story isn't in my mind, but there's clear picture of time portal in my mind. It was like gate after crossing which one could switch time... not like time machine of Back to the Future in which an object (containing you) disappears from present and appears in another time. To import water, they were using a pipe through that time portal.
The bath of hero/villain was also featured in which he filled his bathtub fully with water, but someone disturbed him.
Can you please identify this movie or telefim?

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187324/water-wars-time-travel-tv-show (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

Could it be "The girl from Tomorrow", she travel in a pod-like box but the evil Silverthorn I think invent a portal to steal water from the present time.

Answer (score 5):

This definitely sounds like the Girl From Tomorrow but that was a TV series made in the 90s so can't be too certain.

In it, they have a time gate stolen from the 31st century which the villain (Silverthorn) uses to transport water to the 25th century.

Here's a Youtube link to the episode the time gate appears in:

Comment: This sounds like the one, but can you tell me in which episode water transport was displayed? I remember the water transport scene correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately the Wikipedia episode descriptions stop at episode 4... I believe that particular scene would be in episode 5 or 6 of season 2.  I haven't seen this show since I was 7, was really good for its time :)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "[Charlie Jade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Jade)"?

This cancelled Scifi TV series saw a shadowy organisation transporting water through a wormhole, not from another time but from another universe:

> During the pilot episode, scientists from Vexcor attempt to open a
>   wormhole from the Alphaverse to the Gammaverse in a bid to drain water
>   from the latter to the former. In Gammaverse, terrorists Bern and
>   Reena — aware of Vexcor's intent — prepare to sabotage the facility.
>   Before the stable wormhole can be completed, a massive explosion at
>   the site of the portal (a large open-air water reservoir) leads to a
>   chain reaction explosion that moves through all three universes. This
>   results in Charlie being thrown from Alphaverse into the Betaverse,
>   into a different Cape Town that he is unfamiliar with. Reena is also
>   thrown into the Betaverse.

Answer (score -2):

The movie you may be thinking of is called Ice Pirates.

Comment: No way... There's no Time Travel featured in Ice Pirates.

Comment: technically there was time travel at the very end even though it was reversed