# Water Wars: Time Travel TV Show?

Tags: story-identification

There was this cool tv show I used to watch as a kid (in the 1990's I think). It was about a world where water was extremely rare and people used to fight over it, however there was this person who had this large 3D polyhedron shaped device (big enough to fit a few people in it) that could synthesise water.

Now, this device was either a time travel device or could just make water (not sure but I remember some time travel aspect as they could either remember the world the way it was where water was plentiful or could travel back to it on occasion).

Anyway, would love to know if this rings any bells?????

It was on in the UK (but maybe the US too, not sure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possibly the Australian TV series [The Girl From Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow) from 1990 (or more precisely, the [sequel series from 1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow_Part_II:_Tomorrow%27s_End) which might simply be considered a second season).

The first was mostly set in present day (with a girl from the far future), but the second was set in the year 2500, still the past to the title character, but the dystopian future to the other main cast.

From the Wikipedia description of the second, we see a setup like you remember.

> The year 2500 is a polluted, miserable dystopia, where GlobeCorp owns everything, and the majority of people live in relative squalor. Clean water and uncontaminated food are hard to come by, although the elite enjoy life in comfortable skyscrapers, and the top leaders live in a colony on the moon.

The large polyhedral device you remember was the time capsule itself, technology from the year 3000 which could synthesize water from the atmosphere.

[image]

Comment: This is very close, but I watched some of the episodes on youtube, the 2nd series only seems vaguely familiar. I can't shake the feeling that there is another version of this (may be a British version??)?